# How to get a Javascript alert for radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="comment">
          <form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateform()">
            <label for="fname">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fullname" placeholder="Your name..">

            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail..">

            Rate us<br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rate">
            <label for="radio1">Poor</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rate">
            <label for="radio2">Good</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="rate">
            <label for="radio3">Excelent</label>

            <br>
            <label for="subject">Comments</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateform(){
                var name=document.forms["myform"]["fname"].value;
                var poor = document.getElementById("radio1").checked;
            var good = document.getElementById("radio2").checked;
            var excelent = document.getElementById("radio3").checked;
            var text = document.forms["myform"]["subject"].value;

                if (name == "" || name==null || !name.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
                    alert("Please enter name");
                    return false;
                }
                if (text == "" || text==null || !text.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
                    alert("Please enter valid text");
                    return false;
                }
                else if (poor==true) {
                alert(" Dear "  + name +    " , We appriciate your feedback. You have rated our site as POOR and your comment was " + text);
            return false;
            }
            else if (good==true) {
                alert(" Dear "  + name +    " , We appriciate your feedback. You have rated our site as GOOD and your comment was " + text);
            return false;
            }
                else if (excelent==true) {
                alert(" Dear "  + name +    " , We appriciate your feedback. You have rated our site as EXCELENT and your comment was " + text);
            return false;
            }

            }
        </script>
```

This is part of the code of a comment section I'm creating.I've done the validation for the name and the text area, but i can't find a way to get an alert message saying, *"Dear (name). We appreciate your feedback. You have rated our site as (relevant radio button name) and your comment was (comment on comment area)"*.Can someone tell me how to display this alert message.

(No need validation for the e-mail)

Comment: Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail..">
```

There is a `input type='email'` which, if submitted, will check if this is a valid email.

See [documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what you asked for exactly, but this is a more error proof way to perform validation, and it is really easy to use. https://validatejs.org/, check it out.

Answer (score -1):

i've found a pattern for an email adress =>
 /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

I don't know what the input is gonna be of the textarea but you can check if its filled or not like you did  here =>
name == ""